# Auto threshold in ImageJ/FIJI with Python

Tags: python, imagej

I'm trying to write python scripts in ImageJ and I'm having problems with autothresholding. It won't let me use the `IJ.setAutoThreshold("Default dark")`. An example bit of code is below (with a few things left out for clarity):

```
from ij import IJ, ImagePlus
from java.lang import Runtime, Runnable

import os

for i in filepaths:                        #filepaths being the files I'm opening
    IJ.open(i)
    IJ.run("Split Channels")               #this is splitting a two channel image
    imp = IJ.getImage()        
    imp.close()                            #this is closing the channel I don't want
    IJ.setAutoThreshold("Default dark")    #this is trying to set a threshold
```

Setting the auto threshold here gives

```
AttributeError: type object 'ij.IJ' has no attribute 'setAutoTrheshold'
```

How can I access ImageJ's threshold function?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [javadoc](http://javadoc.imagej.net/ImageJ1/index.html?ij/IJ.html): `IJ` has a method taking two arguments

```
setAutoThreshold(ImagePlus imp, String method)
```

so in your case

```
IJ.setAutoThreshold(imp, "Default dark")
```

should work.